# ASP.NET CORE MVC/ EntityFramewor/ ошибка в выполнении миграции

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

при выполнении команды: dotnet ef database update, появляется ошибка:

```
PM> dotnet ef database update 
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 5.0.4 initialized 'AppDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'myltipleactiveresultsets'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Keyword not supported: 'myltipleactiveresultsets'.
```

Вот сам DbContext

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyFirstProject.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyFirstProject.Domain
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<TextField> TextFields { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ServiceItem> ServiceItems { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole
            {
                Id = "44546e06-8719-4ad8-b88a-f271ae9d6eab",
                Name = "admin",
                NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().HasData(new IdentityUser
            {
                Id = "3b62472e-4f66-49fa-a20f-e7685b9565d8",
                UserName = "admin",
                NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
                Email = "my@email.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "MY@EMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PasswordHash = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>().HashPassword(null, "superpassword"),
                SecurityStamp = string.Empty
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "44546e06-8719-4ad8-b88a-f271ae9d6eab",
                UserId = "3b62472e-4f66-49fa-a20f-e7685b9565d8"
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TextField>().HasData(new TextField
            {
                Id = new Guid("63dc8fa6-07ae-4391-8916-e057f71239ce"),
                CodeWord = "PageIndex",
                Title = "Главная"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<TextField>().HasData(new TextField
            {
                Id = new Guid("70bf165a-700a-4156-91c0-e83fce0a277f"),
                CodeWord = "PageServices",
                Title = "Наши услуги"
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<TextField>().HasData(new TextField
            {
                Id = new Guid("4aa76a4c-c59d-409a-84c1-06e6487a137a"),
                CodeWord = "PageContacts",
                Title = "Контакты"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

И appsettings.json

```
"Project": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=SAINTPC; Database=MyFirstProject; Persist Security Info=false; User ID='sa'; Password='sa'; MyltipleActiveResultSets=True; Trusted_Connection=False;",
    "CompanyName": "Моя компания",
    "CompanyPhone": "+7 (111) 111-11-11",
    "CompanyPhoneShort": "+71111111111",
    "CompanyEmail": "contact@mycompany.com"
```

Уже довольно долго не могу понять: почему не получается занести данные в SQL microsoft, хотя сама миграция выполнилась без проблем

Comment: `MyltipleActiveResultSets=True;` .... `Keyword not supported: 'myltipleactiveresultsets'` ?

Comment: у вас опечатка в `MyltipleActiveResultSets`, попробуйте `MultipleActiveResultSets`